# "java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String" when using AddvalueListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, typeerror

[image]I am working on an Android application with a Firebase backend. Firebase is quite new to me, so I have a few questions.

This is the MainActivity of an Application with 2 EditText Views that writes two values "Name" and "Contact" to the Firebase DB. When they change it retrieves the values and then Logs them through the log.v method.

I get the following error message: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String". Error is in the AddValueEventListener method.

**My DB Structure**

**completefirebasetutorial**

-- Contact: 452145233

-- Name: "Barre"

Can anyone help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference myRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference();

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //map is a data type which stores a key and a value pair
            Map<String,String> map = (Map<String,String>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String name = map.get("Name");
            String contact = map.get("Contact");

            Log.v("Name", name);
            Log.v("Contact",contact);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

public void ButtonClicked(View view) {
    EditText Nametextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterMessage);
    EditText Numbertextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterContact);

    String objectName = Nametextbox.getText().toString();
    myRef = database.getReference("Users").child(objectName);
    myRef.child("Name").setValue(Nametextbox.getText().toString());
    myRef.child("Contact").setValue(Numbertextbox.getText().toString());
}
}
```

Comment: You might want to edit the title of this question, because "Firebase Storage" is a separate product that is mentioned nowhere in this question.

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Have added DB Structure in the main body..

Comment: Please add your database structure... The JSON file or at least an image.

Comment: added the picture..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your phone number is being store as a number (e.g. Long) instead of a String. You may need to change you database schema or JSON or whatever the source is.

Your contact info is being store as the value `452145233` instead of the string `"452145233"`.